How can I achieve full bleed within a nested grid?
I want to have the ability to do full bleeds (displaying an item from edge to edge on the viewport) within my grid setup. I would like to have the item with the class full-bleed to span the design-grid and wrapper-grid.
I am open to other ways of constructing the DOM to get this to work, but I would like to keep using grid instead of absolute positioning.


.wrapper-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min(65ch, 100%) 1fr;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.design-grid {
  display: grid;
  /* I can't have subgrid and declare a new grid */
  /* grid-template-clomns: subgrid; */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.wrapper-grid>* {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.full-bleed {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.item {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
<body class="wrapper-grid">
  <div class="design-grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item full-bleed">This item should go to both edges of the viewport</div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>




the full content or only the background coloration?

@TemaniAfif The full content

Here is an idea using margin with some calculation. Also you don't have to use a nested grid configuration. One grid is enough.
Related article from my blog to understand the use of margin-inline: https://css-tip.com/center-max-width/


.wrapper-grid {
  --w: 65ch; /* the max width*/
  
  margin-inline: max(0px, (100vw - var(--w))/2);
}

.design-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.full-bleed {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  /* this one is the opposite of the above to negate it and get the full bleed effect */
  margin-inline: min(0px, (var(--w) - 100vw)/2);
}

.item {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
<body class="wrapper-grid">
  <div class="design-grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item full-bleed">This item should go to both edges of the viewport</div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>



And in case you want to keep your nested grid


.wrapper-grid {
  --w: 65ch; /* the max width*/
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min(var(--w), 100%) 1fr;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.design-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.full-bleed {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  /* this one is the opposite of the above to negate it and get the full bleed effect */
  margin-inline: min(0px, (var(--w) - 100vw)/2);
}

.item {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
<body class="wrapper-grid">
  <div class="design-grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item full-bleed">This item should go to both edges of the viewport</div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>




Thanks cool idea! Will play with this more. I wish css grid would provide a solution for this problem tho.

You can design your grid using more columns than the content requires and then adjust the column span on the row that needs to fill the screen width.
Note: There is probably a lesser method, but hopefully this gets the point across.


.wrapper-grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.design-grid {
  min-height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'r1c1 r1c2 r1c3 r1c4 r1c5 r1c6' 
    'r2c1 r2c2 r2c3 r2c4 r2c5 r2c6'
    'r3c1 r3c2 r3c3 r3c4 r3c5 r3c6';
  grid-gap: .2rem;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: cyan;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {grid-area: r1c2;}
.item:nth-child(2) {grid-area: r1c3;}
.item:nth-child(3) {grid-area: r1c4;}
.item:nth-child(4) {grid-area: r1c5;}
.item:nth-child(5) {grid-column: span 6 }
.item:nth-child(6) {grid-area: r3c2;}
<body class="wrapper-grid">
  <div class="design-grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item full-bleed">This item should go to both edges of the viewport</div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>




Thanks for this! I tried this approach too and I found that the downside of this of this approach is that the grid-gap is also at the end of the first column and the beginnen of the last column. Which is something that I would like to avoid, because I want to set my own 'container padding' there.

Couldn't you just remove the gap and set only row gap and specify each child's left/right margin? or just specify each child's margin accordingly and have no gap set?

Yes that is possible. But then I have to make sure that that the first and the last item does not have margin on them. A problem that gap solves so nicely. I might be a bit too picky here with the solution, but I just don't see a 'nice' way to solve this.
